# Visio Page Last Edited

Tags: visio

I currently use a `=DOCLASTSAVE()` custom formula field on all of my pages in a Visio document to display the last modified date/time of my Visio Document. I'd like to also be able to display a date/time on each page that indicates when that page was last changed. I looked at the [Visio Page Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page) documentation but did not see anything that jumped out at me.

Other than manually maintaining the field, does anyone have a way of doing this in a more automated fashion? I just want to capture the last date/time for a page whenever it has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is offered is the Document last saved date/time.